# Random Karma PhantomJS Script Error while running tests

Tags: angularjs, jenkins, gulp, phantomjs, karma-runner

I have a gulp task that runs jasmine unit tests for angular using karma test runner. For a while now I've been getting these random `Script Errors` in my Jenkins CI system and as such, the tests fail. These have started after I've added 29 unit tests making a total of 160 unit tests (which is quite less). They dont show any FAILURE. They show ERROR

```
  Pre-population Job Service
    ✓ should be registered
    .getJobList
      ✓ should get a list of pre-population jobs
    .getJobListWithID
      ✓ should get a single pre-population job
    .runJob
      ✓ should run a pre-population job
    .deleteJob
      ✓ should delete a pre-population job
    .editJob
      ✓ should edit a pre-pop job

  Publish Service
    ✓ should be registered
    .getPublishErrors
      ✓ should get an array of publishing errors successfully
      ✓ should not get an array of publishing errors if no data is obtained
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR
  Script error.

PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0): Executed 142 of 153 ERROR (26.945 secs / 15.929 secs)


  Publish Service
    .republish
      ✓ should hit republish endpoint for a distribution
    .republishStatus
      ✓ should hit endpoint for a distribution to verify if it republished or not

  Republish Logs Service
    ✓ should be registered
    .getAllLogs
      ✓ should get an array of republishing logs

  Tasks Data Dump Service
    ✓ should be registered
    .getTasksDataDumpList
      ✓ should get a list of tasks data dump jobs
    .getTasksDataDump
      ✓ should get a single task data dump job
    .getOrganizations
      ✓ should get a list of instances with their sso id
    .runTasksDataDumpJob
      ✓ should run a tasks data dump job
    .deleteTasksDataDumpJob
      ✓ should delete a tasks data dump job
[20:09:50] 'test' errored after 29 s
[20:09:50] Error: Failed 1 tests.
    at /Users/newscred/projects/support-dashboard-interns/client/gulp/unit-tests.js:34:22
    at removeAllListeners (/Users/newscred/projects/support-dashboard-interns/client/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:379:7)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/Users/newscred/projects/support-dashboard-interns/client/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:390:9)
    at Server.g (events.js:291:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at Server.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at emitCloseNT (net.js:1553:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:71:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

In my local machine, it sometimes happen and sometimes it doesn't. But in my Jenkins CI which runs the tests with docker, it FAILS always with this script error. And this script error appears randomly after any test, making it impossible to pinpoint exactly which code is causing this error. Locally with docker, the test passes as well. But in CI it ALWAYS fails no matter what and it fails with `Script Error.` I've removed any code that was pulling from external scripts/ any $watch or $window related test codes as well. NONE of these solutions helped me. These were suggested in the OPEN Github issue https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/1268

I really need a quick fix for this. The github issue is still open which means it isn't solved yet but my project is basically useless without getting this to work. Please help!